# Fetchone return value null in python code

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to make a select with return of an object as the code below. But this object is returning empty, but if I print the records is being printed correctly. I need to return an object as specified below, but this return is null.

I am using Python 3.7 and a PostgreSql Database 11

```py
def selectRowNick(connection, nick):
    with connection:
        try:
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            query = """SELECT * FROM app_row where nick = %s"""
            cursor.execute(query, (nick, ))
            records = cursor.fetchone()
            row = Row()
            row.setId(records[0])
            row.setDescription(records[1])
            row.setAddressIP(records[2])
            row.setControlBoard(records[3])
            row.setNick(records[4])
            return row

        except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
            if (connection):
                print("Failed to select record into table", error)

        finally:
            # closing database connection.
            if (connection):
                cursor.close()
                connection.close()
```

```py
from db_condig import connection
from db_store import *
from Row import Row

row = Row()
row = selectRowNick(connection, "row1")
print(row)
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are having an exception and your code doesn't arrive to `return row`?
Are you sure that the query is returning data?

Comment: Now that I've seen it, an exception is really returning to me

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "testeRow.py", line 5, in <module>
     row = selectRowNick (connection, "row1")
   File "db_store.py", line 59, in selectRowNick
     connection.close ()
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed

Answer (score 0):

`null` isn't something in python. You mean `None` I'm guessing.

From my understanding, `row`, the return value in `selectRowNick()`, is `'null'` or `'NULL'`. If you need it to `None`, you need to do something about it.

Maybe?

```py
return None if row.lower() == 'null' else row
```

Comment: yes, return row, is returning none. However, if I print (records) the records are displayed correctly.

Comment: So, did I address your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not